# How long does a CSRF token lasts?

Tags: plugin-development, security

I did at some point believe that the CSRF token my plugin requests was using expired in the middle of a request, but it turns out that they were never included in the first place.

Still curious, I wonder how long a CSRF token lasts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each session gets it's own CSRF token, so technically it will be valid as long as a session is valid.